# Out-of-proc COM Server Memory Leaks when client invoke CoCreateInstance and closed unexpected

Tags: windows, com, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, com-interop

I have Out-of-Proc, in reality, DllSurrogate COM-Server, written in C++, ATL, mentioned in my previous S.O. [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839719/how-to-consume-com-server-atl-dll-surrogate-in-net-c-sharp-winservice). I am creating and/or connecting to singleton from COM-Server from many clients and C# application, using `CoCreateInstance`. In both of them after finishing using COM-object respective release is called. 
In Delphi it is based in interfaces Release Reference Count when interface go out of scope, in C# it is called `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` and till there seems to be all OK.

The problem is when client application is closed unexpected, like killed from process or crashed. in this case COM-object remain in memory, loaded in DLLHOST.exe.

### Is there some standard way to avoid such leaks? or may be problem is in how is written COM-Server itself (I have sources nut they are not in my responsibility and I don't know ATL)

**EDITED:** I discovering that COM has it own Garbage Collection mechanism which clear remained orphan COM objects after 6-8 minutes (tanks to @Simon Mourier). Now it is the matter of application logic to handle remained orphan COM-object, like re-initialize it or something else.

Comment: COM has a standard Garbage Collection mechanism for out-of-process servers: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171414

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks - it seems this is what i need and missed when was analyzing COM client-server interaction.

Comment: Do you still have a question then?

Comment: Ran some experiments. Timeout when client experiences sudden death is roughly 15 minutes (Windows 10 machine).